# Google-таблицы: разное отображение активных фильтров для разных пользователей таблицы

Tags: google-spreadsheet, фильтры, фильтрация, таблицы, организация

К таблице имеют доступ несколько человек, каждому из них нужный конкретные данные и чтобы было удобнее работать каждый из них использует фильтры для каждого столбика. Кому-то нужны данные1 и соответственно он уменьшает для себя таблицу в нужные размеры с ему нужными данными. Другой человек требует данные2 и соответственно тоже самое, получает индивидуальную таблицу(отфильтрованную) для работы с нужными данными. Но проблема в том, что если 1 человек отфильтрует таблицу, то и у всех остальных людей имеющих доступу к ней таблица будет выглядят как и у первого. Хотя им нужны совершенно другие данные.

Можно ли сделать чтобы каждый мог отфильтровать данные и это не отобразилось у других пользователей. Так же в таблицу постоянно вводят данные. Учитывайте это.

Жду как конкретных предложений по настройке или способов организовать работу офиса.

Comment: Добавьте ещё какие-то тэги. А то только с тэгом `фильтры`, вопрос выглядит безликим.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте именные фильтры, это решит проблему.

Для создания именного фильтра необходимо воспользоваться в главном меню функцией **Данные/Фильтры/Создать новый фильтр**, или использовать выпадающее меню иконки фильтра на панели инструментов. Поля вокруг рабочей области станут тёмно-серыми, и сверху появится дополнительная панель именного фильтра, в которой необходимо присвоить фильтру имя и задать рабочий диапазон. В этом режиме вы можете фильтровать данные как вам угодно - работающие в таблице одновременно с вами не будут видеть этих изменений, если не активируют этот же режим фильтрации. Настройки диапазона и фильтрация данных в режиме именного фильтра сохраняются автоматически.

Таким образом вы можете создать персональный именной фильтр для каждого пользователя, один или несколько, с разными настройками.

Источник:[Справка Google - Редакторы документов](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3540681?hl=ru)

Comment: Я приложил ссылку на соответствующий раздел официальной справки по Google Spreadsheets — куда уж более развернуто? Создавайте любое количество именных фильтров для любых диапазонов, и пусть люди спокойно работают, каждый под своим фильтром — можно манипулировать колоночными фильтрами как угодно, остальные этого не увидят. У меня десяток человек работают одновременно в одной таблице, и никто не мешает друг другу.